# k distinct books in n identical shelves

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways to distribute 6 numbered books into 4 identical shelves?

I solved for 3 books into 2 shelves by taking two cases

a) Selecting all 3 books and keeping it on one self. ( 3C3- 1 way )

b) Selecting 2 books at a time from 3 books and keeping it on one self. ( 3C2 - 3 ways )

Total 4 ways

But for 6 books and 4 shelves there will be much more cases and hence solving by adding each case individually would be difficult. Can you suggest some other way to think about this problem.

Comment: Is there any condition on the number of books in a shelve?

Comment: @VyomYadav I have solved without any restrictions for 3 books and 2 shelves so no there are no restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading the book [*A Walk Through Combinatorics*](https://pdfroom.com/books/a-walk-through-combinatorics-an-introduction-to-enumeration-and-graph-theory/NpgpZ0LB5jr) written by Bona,
indeed your question is an example of Set Partitions in $\S5.2$ of the book.

And the answer is
$$S(6,1)+S(6,2)+S(6,3)+S(6,4)$$
The final result can be found by using the recurrence relation of $S(n,k)$:
$$S(n,k)=S(n-1,k-1)+k\cdot S(n-1,k).$$